# Score not increasing more than one and not displaying on screen

Tags: python

I tried to create a simple snake type game but put Pacman instead of the snake to make the game simple.
I created it in pygame.

My score is not displaying on my game window if I increase it from the class, and the score is not increasing more than one. Please help.

I tried increasing the score in my main game loop and it works just fine, but if I increase the score from the check collisions class, the score increases to 1 and always stays at 1 no matter how much I increase, when Pacman eats a fruit he needs to get +1 score.

````py
class player(object):
    def randomize(self,win,score):
        self.fx = random.randint(0,1250)
        self.fy = random.randint(0,550)
        score += 1
        print("score is",score)
    def check_collisions(score,win):
        pacdraw = pygame.Rect(pac.x+10, pac.y+10, 75, 75)
        pygame.draw.rect(win,(100,100,100),pacdraw,-1)
        fruit = pygame.Rect(pac.fx+10,pac.fy+10, 40, 30)
        pygame.draw.rect(win,(100,100,100),fruit,-1)
        collide = pacdraw.colliderect(fruit)
        if collide:
            pac.randomize(win,score)

# score = 0
scorefont = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
def display_score(score,win):
    display = scorefont.render(f'score: {score}', True, (225, 225, 225))
    win.blit(display, (10, 10))
def Redrawgamewindow():
    win.blit(bg, (-300,-200))
    win.blit(cherry, (pac.fx, pac.fy))
    check_collisions(score,win)
    display_score(score,win)
    pac.draw(win)```
````

Comment: Please have a look at the code to have a better view of the problem.

Comment: Please let me know if you want me to show the whole code to better understand the problem, The code is a bit long, so I just put the part that's most affected.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to actually edit without asking first, so, if I'm going to ask anyway, better to leave a comment as a suggestion instead: from the edit history and checking the screenshot attached initially with the code, I think `check_collisions` wasn't meant to be inside the class (because there's no `self` argument, and the indentation was different). Edit: also, the `player` class wasn't there originally, so, could you also add all the properties it has?

Comment: Yeah, Actually I tried trial and error by trying to place check_collisions outside the class and increasing the score, but that didn't work.The player class was there before but it was outside the image

Comment: Thanks, everyone! My problem has been solved. I defined the score variable in the class itself by self.score and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using class, so you don't have to pass arguments to the function manually 
You can use

```
def __init__(self, win):
    self.score = 0
    self.win = win
```

and you can access the 'score' by 'self'

```
def randomize(self):
    self.fx = random.randint(0,1250)
    self.fy = random.randint(0,550)
    self.score += 1
    print("score is", self.score)
```

so that 'score' is stored on the Player class, not passing to the function 
so if

```
player = Player(win)
```

then you can access to player's score variable as below

```
def display_score(score, win):
    display = scorefont.render(f'score: {player.score}', True, (225, 225, 225))
    win.blit(display, (10, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the variable from `score += 1` to `self.score += 1`

Answer (score 0):

In the `check_collisions` you try to update the score, but numbers are passed by value and not by reference

Try to return the score and assign when you call this function on mainloop